# ContentDocuments under Email only visible if there's an Attachment?

Tags: email, emailfileattachment

I have an EmailHandler that creates a ContentDocument for every BinaryAttachment/TextAttachment.

What I need, is these files to be visible under the Email in de Case Feed. This works, but not completely as I'd expect. Two examples:

**Email 1**

1. Two images in the emailbody, called Inline.png, and one in the signature
2. One image as real 'attachment'

The images are stored as ContentDocuments, and visible in the email.

[image: ContenDocuments only]

**Email 2**

Then, I made an update and sent the same email again. Now, the EmailHandler stores the BinaryAttachments both as ContentDocument **and** Attachment. FYI: You see the filenames of the original BinaryAttachments in the htmlBody of the email.

Now, the images are clickable under the email on the Case Feed layout, as I would like it (almost):
[image: Attachments+ContentDocuments show up]

It looks like Salesforce only shows clickable ContentDocuments if there's also an Attachment? Is this intended behavior?

I would like to have:

1. BinaryAttachments stored as ContentVersions (I want to link them to the Case as well)
2. Those files are visible as grey, clickable buttons under the email (as you see in the screenshot now)
3. Those files must not be duplicated (as you see in the screenshot now)

How do I achieve that?

Comment: I have been trying to figure out the same thing for a while. What I found is that to get an attachment to show up there you need to create a FeedAttachment record. When you create an EmailMessage related to the case a FeedItem is created automatically, however there seems to be no link to the EmailMessage on the FeedItem, only to the case, and the creation of FeedAttachment randomly seems to work in some scratch orgs but not in others.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds promising!